# Can not get the value in the strong tag

Tags: xpath

The part of HTML code is;

```
*...
<ul class="daily_summary">
    <li class="odd">
        <span> TODAY'S <br> TEST <br> RESULT  </span>
            <strong class="todays-test-result">123.987</strong>
    </li>
</ul>
...*
```

XPath code : `//li/span`
returns **TODAY's TEST RESULT**

But;
XPath code : `//li/span[@strong='todays-test-result']`
does not return the value (**123.987**)

How can I get the value with XPATH?

Answer (score 0):

`strong` tag is not in the `span` tag. Therefore your XPath should not include it. Following XPath should work : `//li/strong[@class="todays-test-result"]`

@Rixcy 's comment is pretty helpful.

> Also to add on to this, the @ selector is used for attributes on a tag, so in this case strong is the tag, but @class is the attribute. A useful resource for xpath is: devhints.io/xpath - @Rixcy

Comment: Also to add on to this, the @ selector is used for attributes on a tag, so in this case strong is the tag, but @class is the attribute. A useful resource for xpath is: https://devhints.io/xpath

Comment: @MuratDikici [xpath](https://miro.medium.com/max/3228/1*VUorLulWvr_rMUTLov-H3w.gif) Maybe you can copy the XPath like this.